# Where is the OWA cache

Tags: windows, outlook-web-access

Where does Outlook Web Access cache attachments?  Is there a folder similar to Content.Outlook  for OWA?

Answer (score 2):

If you are refering to the server OWA cache folder. the cache directory for your configuration is usually: */path/to/owa/owa-data/caches/1)*

If it's on the client side, it should be in the Internet Temp folder.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure they get lumped in with other temporary internet files.